# Is there an Oracle Open Cursor (ORA-01000) leak in ColdFusion?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, memory-leaks, coldfusion-7

using CFMX7 and Oracle 10g ent on a query-intensive and active web site, I'm having a problem that some of the Oracle connections in my web server connection pool are accumulating open cursors.  (In JDBC parlance this might be called a ResultSet object leak.)

This is a confusing situation in Oracle; read here for an explanation.
http://www.orafaq.com/node/758

Any how, it's not cached PreparedStatements that are leaking, it's actually ResultSets.

My DBAs have set the OPEN_CURSORS parameter to 500 per connection.  Fairly frequently, my connections get up to 450+, which triggers a DBA alarm (because we hope to avoid smacking web app users with ORA-01000 cursor exhaustion errors).

Does anybody know if there's a bug in ColdFusion (MX7) that causes this problem?  Is there any way programatically to use CF to generate a ResultSet object leak (called a cfquery leak in CF)?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information that might be helpful.

http://jehiah.cz/a/maximum-open-cursors-exceeded